# How to import data from a file as list in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a large *.txt file that has real numbers. I want to import and Execute the RootMeanSquare function on it, but the output of that function is not a real number.

```
a.txt:
```

0.00005589924852471949
0.000036651199287161235
0.000016275882123536572
-4.955137498989977*^-6
-0.00002680629351951319
-0.000048814313574683916

```
ah=Import["a.txt", "List"];
RootMeanSquare[ah]
Sqrt[7.83436*10^-9 + ("-4.955137498989977*^-6")^2]/Sqrt[6]
```

In my opinion, the problem is in the number -4.955137498989977*^-6.
Please help me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The import yields a string, so split it and convert to numeric expressions.

```
ah = ToExpression@StringSplit@Import["a.txt"]
```

`StringSplit` splits a string at whitespaces by default.

`ToExpression` is listable, so it operates on the string list in one step.